# Getting extensive summary from group_by and summary

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, janitor

I want to find out how long the median time from last vaccine till admission to ICU is. I have a dataset looking like this:

```
ID <- c(1:20)
Group <- c("1. vacc + unvacc", "2. vacc", "3. vacc", "1. vacc + unvacc", "2. vacc", "3. vacc", "1. vacc + unvacc", "2. vacc", "3. vacc",
           "1. vacc + unvacc", "2. vacc", "3. vacc", "1. vacc + unvacc", "2. vacc", "3. vacc", "1. vacc + unvacc", "2. vacc", "3. vacc",
           "1. vacc + unvacc", "2. vacc")
Status <- c("Dead", "Alive", "Dead", "Alive", "Dead", "Alive", "Dead", "Alive", "Dead", "Alive", "Dead", "Alive", 
            "Dead", "Alive", "Dead", "Alive", "Dead", "Alive", "Dead", "Alive")

Months <- c(5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 8, 2, 5, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 8, 2, 5)
```

I have tried:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group, Status) %>%
  summarise(ICU_median = median(Months)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Status,
    values_from = ICU_median
  ) %>%
  adorn_totals("col", name = "All") %>% 
  adorn_totals("row", name = "Overall") %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols= -Group,
    names_to = "Status", 
    values_to = "ICU median"
  )
```

Which gives the following output:

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Group'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Group            Status `ICU median`
   <chr>            <chr>         <dbl>
 1 1. vacc + unvacc Alive           5  
 2 1. vacc + unvacc Dead            2  
 3 1. vacc + unvacc All             7  
 4 2. vacc          Alive           5.5
 5 2. vacc          Dead            3  
 6 2. vacc          All             8.5
 7 3. vacc          Alive           6  
 8 3. vacc          Dead            2  
 9 3. vacc          All             8  
10 Overall          Alive          16.5
11 Overall          Dead            7  
12 Overall          All            23.5
```

Which is almost what I want, but stil far from - since I want to know what the median months from last vaccine till ICU admission for every subgroup. My problem is, that the "All" group is being added together, probably from the `adorn_totals` but i can't figure out how add and divide by 2 since I dont want the summed value but the median for all within the 1. vacc + unvacc. Furthermore, would it be possible to insert two more columns with 25. and 75. quantiles for each row/subgroup? (that has not worked for me at all). Desired output would be:

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Group'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Group            Status `ICU median`  25. quartile  75. quartile
   <chr>            <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 1. vacc + unvacc Alive           5               x             y
 2 1. vacc + unvacc Dead            2               z             d
 3 1. vacc + unvacc All             **3.5**  
 4 2. vacc          Alive           5.5
 5 2. vacc          Dead            3  
 6 2. vacc          All             **4.25**
 7 3. vacc          Alive           6  
 8 3. vacc          Dead            2  
 9 3. vacc          All             **4**  
10 Overall          Alive          Average median for all alive
11 Overall          Dead           Average median for all dead  
12 Overall          All            Average median for all
```

Comment: I'm confused by the calculation for "All" for a `Group` - wouldn't you want the median for all cases in the `Group` (both alive and dead), instead of taking the median of two medians?

Comment: Hey @Ben you are completely correct, I must have had my thoughts somewhere else at a bad time. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Please clarify:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)

df %>%
  group_by(Group, Status) %>%
  summarise(ICU_median = median(Months)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Status,
    values_from = ICU_median
  ) %>%
  adorn_totals("col", name = "All") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(median_x = median(c(Alive, Dead))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols= -Group,
    names_to = "Status", 
    values_to = "ICU median"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Group= ifelse(Status == "median_x", "Overall", Group)) %>% 
  arrange(Group) %>% 
  rename(ICU_median = `ICU median`) %>% 
  mutate(ICU_median = ifelse(Status == "All", ICU_median/2, ICU_median))
```

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Group            Status   ICU_median
   <chr>            <chr>         <dbl>
 1 1. vacc + unvacc Alive          5   
 2 1. vacc + unvacc Dead           2   
 3 1. vacc + unvacc All            3.5 
 4 2. vacc          Alive          5.5 
 5 2. vacc          Dead           3   
 6 2. vacc          All            4.25
 7 3. vacc          Alive          6   
 8 3. vacc          Dead           2   
 9 3. vacc          All            4   
10 Overall          median_x       3.5 
11 Overall          median_x       4.25
12 Overall          median_x       4
```

Comment: Hey again TarJae. I see, that I need to be more clear in what I wished for: I would like the "All" rows to contain the median value for both dead and alive in the ICU_median column, as @Ben also stated in an above comment.  Furthermore (since my skills are very limited) would be it possible to add two columns more of percentiles (e.g. 25. and 75.?)

Comment: have you seen my comment?